# Leaking power off of a coil

Tags: arduino, power

I am trying to make a wireless door opener by adding a small Arduino with a relay switch into our home phone. Unfortunately, that home phone operates without a power source, it has wires for audio and for the door opener coil only.

The idea is: Since the door coil will not trigger with a small current, I could draw some power out of the coil circuit. I found that the coil operates on AC between 8 und 200 Volts.

The Arduino operates at 5V DC.

As a beginner in electronics,  I am unsure how to to this safely, while protecting the Arduino. Can you point me into the right direction?

Comment: I think the right direction is to use a separate 5 volt power supply for the Arduino.

Comment: Sadly, there is no power source nearby. It's this or nothing.

Comment: "AC between 8 und 200 Volts." .. that's rather a large range. I think this is doable (inject 5VAC, extract with transformer, deal with surges) but fiddly. The power to the coil circuit must come from somewhere, can't you put the arduino at the other end of that wire? We could do with a diagram.

Comment: 8 to 200V? Are you sure? That seems to be an unbelievably wide range for a coil to work over ...